# Combination of simple tensors - II

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, tensor-products, tensor

This is a follow-up question to [Combination of simple tensors](https://mathoverflow.net/q/466799/503265).

I am interested in devising an alternative norm (I mean, other than the usual $\pi$ or $\epsilon$ norms) in the tensor product of two Banach spaces.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two Banach spaces and let $X\otimes Y$ their tensor product. Let $u\in X\otimes Y$ and $A(u)$ be the collection of all finite sets of simple tensors of type $S^\alpha=\{x_1^\alpha\otimes y_1^\alpha,\dots ,x_n^\alpha\otimes y_n^\alpha\}$ (where $\alpha$ belongs to a suitable, generally uncountable set of indices $I$) such that:

1. $u=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^\alpha\otimes y_i^\alpha,$
2. For every $\alpha\in I$, there is no subset with at least two elements of $\{x_1^\alpha\otimes y_1^\alpha,\dots ,x_n^\alpha\otimes y_n^\alpha\}$ such that the sum of its elements is a simple tensor.

**Q1:** Is it possible that $\cap_{\alpha\in I} S^\alpha=\emptyset$?

**Q2:** Is it possible that $\inf_{\alpha\in I}m(S^\alpha)= 0$, where $m(S^\alpha)$ is the largest product of type $||x_i^\alpha||_{X}||y_i^\alpha||_{Y}$ in each set $S^\alpha$ and assuming $u\ne 0$?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what is meant by the set $S_k$. Can you add a description?

Comment: @WillieWong Clarified, Thanks!

Comment: What is $S_k$? It's still not clear.

Comment: In Q2, you mean $\inf_(^\alpha)=0$ for some nonzero element of $\otimes $, right? Otherwise it's trivial.

Comment: @Uagi yes of course, I corrected

Answer (score 2):

Take $X = Y= M_2$ and consider the tensor $e_1 \otimes e_1 + e_2 \otimes e_2$. You get the same result for any choice of orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{C}^2$, so there can already be two expressions for a tensor that share no common simple tensors.